# Formatting a Pivot Table in Python

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, format, dataframe

I am trying to reformat a table based on counts in different columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'X' : ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X3', 'X3'], 'Y' : ['Y2','Y1','Y1','Y1', 'Y2'], 'Z' : ['Z3','Z1','Z1','Z2','Z1']})

   Number   X   Y   Z
0       1  X1  Y2  Z3
1       2  X2  Y1  Z1
2       3  X3  Y1  Z1
3       4  X3  Y1  Z2
4       5  X3  Y2  Z1
```

I want the top row to be X sorted by frequency (X3 first because it appears twice) Then for each X value, count up the frequency of its Y and Z values and print the one that shows up the most.

```
   X3  X2  X1
Y  Y1  Y1  Y2           
Z  Z1  Z1  Z3
```

So far I have code that can sort

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'X' : ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X3', 'X3'], 'Y' : ['Y2','Y1','Y1','Y1', 'Y2'], 'Z' : ['Z3','Z1','Z1','Z2','Z1']})
pivot = df.pivot_table(index='X', columns=['Y', 'Z'], values = 'Number', aggfunc='count')
# clean the table from NaNs (not necessary, but more beautiful):
pivot.fillna(0, inplace=True)
pivot['sum'] = pivot.sum(axis=1)
pivot.sort('sum', ascending=False, inplace=True)
df = pivot[:5].transpose()
df.to_csv('sorted.csv')
```

and outputs:

```
Y   Z   X3  X1  X2
Y1  Z1  1   0   1
Y1  Z2  1   0   0
Y2  Z1  1   0   0
Y2  Z3  0   1   0
sum     3   1   1
```

But it's still not what I'm looking for, can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a custom `mode` function because [`pandas.Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html#pandas.Series.mode) does not work if nothing occurs at least twice; though the one below is not the most efficient one, it does the job:

```
>>> mode = lambda ts: ts.value_counts(sort=True).index[0]
>>> cols = df['X'].value_counts().index
>>> df.groupby('X')[['Y', 'Z']].agg(mode).T.reindex(columns=cols)
   X3  X1  X2
Y  Y1  Y2  Y1
Z  Z1  Z3  Z1
```

note that in your sample frame, `X1` and `X2` are tied in number of occurances.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Counter to get the most common elements.  This is returned as tuple of pairs of the item and the number of occurrences, so use list comprehension to select just the items (i.e. i[0] is the item).

```
from collections import Counter

X = [i[0] for i in Counter(df.X).most_common()]
```

Then use list comprehension and `.loc` to iterate through the most common Xs and select the most common 'Y' and 'Z' values.

```
Y = [Counter(df.loc[df.X == x, 'Y']).most_common(1)[0][0] for x in X]

Z = [Counter(df.loc[df.X == x, 'Z']).most_common(1)[0][0] for x in X]

>>> pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'Y': Y, 'Z': Z}).T
    0   1   2
X  X3  X2  X1
Y  Y1  Y1  Y2
Z  Z1  Z1  Z3
```